# React Nested loops

Tags: reactjs

I have some grouped data that I would like to render like such:

```
RowGroupTableHeader 
RowGroup1
RowGroup1-row1
RowGroup1-row2
RowGroup2
RowGroup2-row1
RowGroup2-row2
RowGroup3-row3
```

Normally, I would do a loop through the groups, and within each loop, I would have an internal loop to go through each of the rows.

However, because I'm working with accessibility, div structures are very strict.  eg. you cannot just throw in a surrounding container around div[role=rowgroup].  i.e. each rowgroup needs to be at the same level.

As such, I cannot use the usual Array.map() nested within each other because after the first iteration, I am expected to close the return() and cannot start a new Array.map().

Anyone got any ideas how I can achieve this?

Is there a wrapper component out there that can render its contents without the wrapper?  eg. {content}?

Thanks.
John.

Comment: why not just have a row component that renders the appropriate type based on the data you have? aka use a wrapping component that instead of rendering a surrounding container just renders the appropriate element.

Comment: It's very unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. We need more information. Give us some example code, sample data, and a clear explanation of what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question. But your last sentence leads me to believe that you want to to write a React class that renders its child directly, without wrapping it in an outer element like `div`? If so, that is possible, but ONLY if you pass a SINGLE valid React component in as a child.

The following *should* work:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        if(React.Children.count(this.props.children) === 1){
              // If there is only one child, return it directly, unwrapped
              return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
        } else {
              // Otherwise, return all children wrapped in div
              return <div className="foo">{this.props.children}</div>
        }       
    }
}

...

// Later on...

<Foo><div>Hello, world!</div></Foo>
// Would render simply as 
// <div>
//     Hello, world!
// </div>

<Foo><div>Bar</div><div>Baz</div></Foo>
// Would render as 
// <div class="foo">
//     <div>Bar</div>
//     <div>Baz</div>
// </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for.  Because it's a given that there will be more than 2 children nodes, and thus, by using this component, it will always render a wrapper div (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Imagine if I'm relying on this to nest TR tags.  IE would not accept having DIVs in between TRs.  This solution would force me to use DIVs and not TABLE semantics.